# Ios UNUserNotification Content Attachement (Image) resize/hide on notification expansion (Long click)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

I have an app which shows local notification with content attachment as below image:

[image: Notification in default state]

Now when i click to show the notification actions button, the image gets enlarged and thus my image gets blurred. I tried to find the ways to show the action buttons but not expand the notification view to show the content attachment big and blur. My current output is

[image: Expanded notification image]

So, am i missing something with these rich notification in ios, or there is just no way to hide the content. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem months ago and after much research and trying I finally found the solution to the problem. I hope, this will be helpful for anyone who faces the same problem in near future.

For this I created a new target in my project i.e. Notification Content Extension and added in my project and updated the content of notification extension with a custom xib view

For more details, please go through the below link, I got all the help from it.

https://www.appcoda.com/user-notifications-ios12/